# Syncfusion DoubleTextBox - NegativeColor

Tags: c#, winforms, syncfusion

using doubleTextBoxes from Syncfusion i am using the NegativeColor attribute to specify different textcolors for negative values. This works fine if i type in a negative value manually in my textboxes. However i have some textboxes that are filled automatically by DataBinding:

```
this.txtExample.DataBindings.Add(this.txtExample.GetPropertyName((x) => x.BindableValue), mViewModel, mViewModel.GetPropertyName((x) => x.TestProperty));
```

I tried binding my Property to "Text" and "DoubleValue" instead of "BindableValue", but the text color is not changing for negative values. Any Ideas why the DoubleTextBoxes are behaving this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the same with the Syncfusion DoubleTextBox and the Negative color applied properly in the reported case.

Here is the sample and code snippet for your reference.

```
    class ViewModel
{
    Form1 frm = new Form1();
    Data data = new Data();
    public ViewModel(Form1 _frm)
    {
        frm = _frm;
        foreach (Control ctrl in frm.Controls)
            if (ctrl is DoubleTextBox)
                (ctrl as DoubleTextBox).DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "unit");
        Application.Run(frm);
    }
}

public class Data
{
    private double n_unit = -5;

    public double unit
    {
        get { return n_unit; }
        set { n_unit = value; }
    }
}
```

Sample Link :http://www.syncfusion.com/uploads/user/directTrac/General/DoubleTextBox-NegativeValues1459287934.zip

Comment: Thank you for taking that much time to answer my question! Your example works fine for me and helped me understand my problem: I didn't mention before that my DoubleTextBoxes are disabled (Enabled = false) to prevent any userinput. While the negative Color attribute works in design mode even for disabled DoubleTextBoxes, the text is greyed out at runtime when i bind negative values to it. This however behaves the same way when i assign a negative value without any databinding. So to rephrase my question: Is there a way to use the negativeColor attribute on disabled DoubleTextBoxes?